# How to convert a simple JSONObject into HashMap Key,Value pairs in java

Tags: java, json

I have a simple JSON object like this:

```
 String jsonString = new String( "{ 
    "table": { "column1" : "description1", 
"column2" : "description2", 
"columnN" : "descriptionN" } }" );
```

What I need to do is create a HashMap or Map to generate this HTML using a forEach with JSTL:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td id="column1">description1</td>
    <td id="column2">description2</td>
    <td id="columnN">descriptionN</td>
    </tr>
...
    </table>
```

JSON STRUCTURE CANNOT CHANGE.

Comment: What about using a JSON library?

Comment: string operations should do it ?

Comment: Yes that's the idea but how? I'm trying to iterate "table" but I don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove all `quotation`, `colons`, `commas` and `bracket` chars from the string (or replace them with spaces, in case your string don't have spaces between the words, so you can split latter). Also remove the substring `"table"`.

Then, all you'll have is `columns and descriptions`, it becomes easier to iterate after used the `split` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = new String( "{ \"table\": { \"column1\" : \"description1\", \"column2\" : \"description2\", \"columnN\" : \"descriptionN\" } }" );
        json = json.replace("{", "")
                .replace("}", "")
                .replace("\"", "")
                .replace("table:", "");
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String[] elems = json.split(",");

        for (String string : elems) {
            String[] keyval = string.split(":");

            map.put(keyval[0].trim(), keyval[0].trim());
        }

        //Printing the map
        for (Entry<String, String> kv : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(kv.getKey() + " : " + kv.getValue());
        }
```

If you want to keep the keys sorted, you might consider using TreeMap instead of HashMap